# How can I redirect some (but not all) http requests on one IIS host to https on another IIS host?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

We have the following requirements:

- redirect **http**://**host1**.domain.com/**resource1**/* to **https**://**host2**.domain.com/**resource1**/* (retaining everything including /resource1/* and query strings, etc.)
- do NOT redirect http://**host1**.domain.com/**resource2**/* at all
- we cannot use Application Request Routing
- IIS 7.5

We can use either redirect or rewrite, whichever works. It seems like setting up an inbound rewrite rule with the 'reverse proxy' option (which creates a condition using an Input with {CACHE_URL}) comes close, but I cannot get it to work with a Pattern in the 'Match URL' section of /resource1/*.  Redirect seems to enable redirecting a resource to another resource on the same host only, not on a different host.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL Rewrite for that. Just add in your web.config of your application something like below where it is adding a condition to match only the host name (host1.domain.com) and matching using regular expressions the resource1 and passing that to the action:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect resource1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="resource1/.*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^host1.domain.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://host2.domain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```